# puppeteer instagram igtv не удачная загрузка видео

Tags: instagram, chromium

Гружу видео через chrome - всё в порядке. 
Через chromium выдаёт ошибку "видео повреждено или в нем используется неподдерживаемый кодирования"
Есть идеи? даже не знаю куда шевельнутся..

Answer (score 0):

вот тут https://chromium.woolyss.com/ скачал портабл и содержимое папки bin в "..puppeteer.local-chromium\win64-672088\chrome-win" thanks https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromium/comments/6awib7/h264_support_in_chromium_windows/